# Find the value of $n$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field having $5^n$ elements .Also $F$ has an element which satisfies $x^{5^n}=1$  such that $x\neq 1$.
Find $n$ .

**My try**:

Let $x\in F $ satisfy $x^{5^n}=1$ .Obviously the group $F^{*}=F\setminus \{0\}$ is cyclic. Consider the cyclic group generated by $x$ i.e $\langle x\rangle $. Also $|F^{*}|=5^n-1$

Let $o(x) =t$ .Now $t$ divides $5^n-1$ since order of an element divides order of the group. Since $x^{5^n}=1\implies t $ divides $5^n$.

Thus $t$ divides both $5^n$ and $5^n-1\implies x=1$  but $x\neq 1$ .Hence no such $n$ exists.

Is the solution correct 
?Am  I missing something.Please help

Comment: The non-zero elements satisfy $x^{5^n-1}=1$, not $x^{5^n}=1$.

Comment: Or, if you prefer, all elements satisfy $x^{5^n}=x$.

Comment: @almagest; it is the hypothesis of the problem that $x^{5^n}=1$

Comment: Read the 3rd para where I have written that $t$ divides $5^n-1$@almagest @Captain Lama

Comment: @learnmore Ok. In that case, it is a strange problem. There certainly does exist a field with $5^n$ elements for any integer $n>0$. As you say, it is easy to show that no element $x\ne1$ in such a field satisfies $x^{5^n}=1$. So at least one of the two statements in the question is false.